# Open Subset of Hilbert Cube

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

In an exercise I was asked to prove that given $y=(y_n)\in H^\infty,N\in\mathbb{N},$ and $\epsilon>0$ the set $A=\{x=(x_n)\in H^\infty:|x_k-y_k|<\epsilon,k=1,\dots,N\}$ is open in $H^\infty$.

The set $H^\infty$ called the Hilbert cube is the set of all real sequences $(x_n)$ for which $|x_n|\leq1$ for $n=1,2,\dots$

In my attempt I fixed an $x\in A$ so that if there exists a $\delta>0$ so that for any sequence $(z_n)\in B_\delta(x)$, $z$ would be in $A$. I would have proved the statement. I work with norm $||\cdot||_1$.

So I tried the following:
\begin{align}
|z_i-y_i|&\leq\sum\limits_{i=1}^N|z_i-y_i|\\
&\leq\sum\limits_{i=1}^N|z_i-x_i|+\sum\limits_{i=1}^N|y_i-x_i| \\
&\leq\delta+N\epsilon \\
\end{align}
This would give $\delta=\epsilon(1-N)\leq0$, but we need $\delta>0$ so my upperbound was too big, any ideas on how to proceed on this problem?

Comment: Maybe the inequality $\| \cdot \|_{\infty} \le \| \cdot \|_1$ can come in handy. It implies for example that any open ball in $\ell^{\infty}$ norm contains an open ball in $\ell^1$ norm.

Answer (score 2):

Take $\delta=\max\limits_{1\leq i\leq N}\{|x_i-y_i|\}<\varepsilon$ then for $z\in B_{\varepsilon - \delta}(x)$ and $i=1,\dots,N$:
\begin{align}
|z_i-y_i|&\leq |z_i-x_i| + |y_i-x_i| \\
&\leq ||z-x||_\infty + \delta \\
&< \varepsilon - \delta + \delta \\
&=\varepsilon
.\end{align}
So $z\in A$. I used the infinite norm $||\cdot||_\infty$ here instead.